# tab menu + side panel - how to organize menu and "context menu"

Tags: design-patterns, menu, dashboard, contextual-menu, web

I have a dashboard, with tab menu (tabs over the content) and a side panel with a vertical menu.

My question is: I would like to make one menu (tab or side panel) as first level menu and the other menu for options inside a specific context.

for example:

On my tabs i have three menus (users, analytics and categories). After that i click over one of those, i.e users, then my left menu will show options related with users (manage, audit, etc). I could do as well the opposite, at the left menu, users, analytics and categories, and as soon as i click on users, i get three tabs over my content (manage, audit and etc).

So, how to decide, which model is better? What i was thinking as decision point is, which menu can have more elements, since too many tabs don't looks nice.

any other tip or idea?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As a user, my instinct would be to regard the tabs as the top-level menu. Being the highest element, it's the first thing I read, and so it's intuitive that it'd be the first 'point of decision'.

You can resolve further confusion by employing three techniques:

1. Don't let the side menu share any of the tab menu's vertical space.
2. Don't be tempted to put any tab items in the side menu. That would feel natural for a 'home' tab or page, but it'll actually confuse your users in the long run
3. Make sure the side menu looks as though it's *within* each tab. For instance, prefer the form[image]

...over

[image: The submenu doesn't obviously belong 'inside' each tab]